# Polynomial time approximation of knapsack

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, knapsack-problem, np

The [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) can be solved in `O(n²V)` time where `V = max(v[i], i = 1,..,n)` denotes the maximum value of any item. If we "change units" by a rounding parameter `θ = ε/n * V` and consider modified values `y[i] = ceil(v[i]/θ)`, we obtain a running time of `O(n³/ε)` for any *fixed* `ε > 0`.

In the book *Algorithm Design* by *Jon Kleinberg*, they state:

> The dependence on the desired precision `ε` is not polynomial, as the
>   running time includes `1/ε` rather than `log 1/ε`.

First of all, the whole idea behind the term *pseudo-polynomial* is not exactly clear to me, even though I've read some articles about it. However, besides this knowledge gap, I mainly ask myself why the dependence on `ε` would be polynomial, if the running time would include `log 1/ε` instead of `1/ε`.

Answer (score 1):

Whether a problem is polynomial-time or not depends on how its instances are encoded. For example, I can define a problem PADDED-SATISFIABILITY whose valid instances consist of a Boolean formula with n variables followed by 2^n junk bits. Thanks to the padding, PADDED-SATISFIABILITY is solvable in polynomial time (unlike, presumably, SATISFIABILITY, which is NP-hard).

When the instances involve integers, it is customary to assume an encoding where the number of bits used to represent a positive integer is about log2 of that integer. A *pseudo-polynomial-time* algorithm, in this context, means that, if we switch from a binary representation of positive integers to unary, so that they require exponentially (!) more bits to be represented, then the algorithm is polynomial-time.

If we make the (frequent) assumption that 1/ε is a positive integer, then Kleinberg is pointing out that a polynomial dependence would be on log 1/ε, since that is approximately the number of bits required to specify that parameter in binary. The number of bits in a unary representation would be approximately 1/ε.

Comment: `log 1/ε` is approximately the number of bits required to store `1/ε` in binary - That's absolutely clear to me, but why is it an issue? Couldn't we argue in the same manner about any `n` in `O(n^k)`? Even when `n` is just a loop counter, we need to store that value (in general). So, what makes `n` different from `1/ε`? [Moreover, why would we consider a unary representation of any parameter?]

Comment: @0xbadf00d If `n` is, say, the number of elements in a list, then the list elements themselves take up a linear number of bits, making it sort of irrelevant how `n` is represented. If `n` is just a number (e.g., for factoring), then it gets treated the same way as `1/ε`.

Comment: @0xbadf00d The reason to think about unary representations is that they're how pseudo-polynomial-time formally is defined. People often ask about knapsack variants here on Stack Overflow; one of the comments or answers often is "it's NP-hard; you're out of luck". Since knapsack is only weakly NP-hard, however, there exists an algorithm that works well on small integer inputs, which is very useful in practice. [3-partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem), on the other hand, is no easier for small integer inputs.